# How to add video with transparent background into Mmoviepy.video.compositing.CompositeVideoClip's clips

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to include video with transparent background into the CompositeVideoClip's clip array, but when I get the result video, my transparent video is fully covering another video.

```
clip_1 = VideoFileClip("video1.mp4")

transparent = VideoFileClip("transparent.mp4", has_mask=True)

transparent = transparent.set_position((45,150))

final_clip = CompositeVideoClip([clip_1, transparent.set_start(5)])

final_clip.write_videofile("final.mp4", codec='libx264', fps=3)
```